# How to find out if a given string is HTML Escaped or not?

Tags: javascript, html, string, escaping

Is there any method to find out if the given string is HTML Escaped or not?

Consider the following javascript code:

```
<script>
var str="hello";
var str_esc=escape(str);

document.write(isHTMLEscaped(str)) // *Should print False*

document.write(isHTMLEscaped(str_esc)); // *Should print True*

</script>
```

Is there any method equivalent to **isHTMLEscaped** in the above case?

Comment: What's your exact goal ?

Comment: My goal is to find out if the given string to my method as a parameter is HTML escaped or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that using

```
escape(unescape(str))
```

will always provide an escaped string. And the unescape string will do nothing unless the string itself contains escaped expressions.

Note: should have used encodeURI(decodeURI(str)) instead as escape is now depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As `"hello"==escape("hello")`, no, you can't at all guess if escaping was applied.

If you want to know if it's probable that the string has been escaped, then you might test

```
var wasProbablyEscaped = /%\d\d/.test(str);
var wasProbablyNotEscaped = !wasProbablyEscaped && /%\d\d/.test(escape(str));
```

as escaping adds `%` followed by two digits when something has to be escaped. But you can't be totally sure as some strings don't change when you escape them.

In your case, I'd probably advise you not to escape if `wasProbablyEscaped` is true.

Comment: What i want is to know if escape was applied or not by means of code....as in isEscapeApplied(escape("abcd")) should return true and isEscapeApplied("hello") should return false. I just want to know if a given string is escaped or not

Comment: Using only the string, you can't know that. Both a source string and the escaped version are normal strings and they even may be equal, as in your example.

Comment: So, how can we figure out if given string is escaped or not?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. In what context are you in need of such a distinction ? Do you want to know if the string can be displayed as it is ? Or what N

Comment: I have to escape my htmlcontent to send over the http. Now this content might already be escaped or might not be. if it isn't, then my code works fine it just taked this html string and escapes it but if it is already escaped, it creates another layer of encoding which causes an issue at the client side as the client-side now would need to remove these 2 layers which i dont want. So, all i want to know is if it is already escaped or do i need to do it before sending to my client

Comment: OK, so you don't really want to know if some escaping has yet be done but if you should escape. Then I'd advise you not to escape if `/%\d\d/.test(str)` is true.

Comment: It can't. If you have `"l%27oasis"`, this may be an escaped string or that the user decided to type just that.